# AOP tools for logging with method local variables C#

Tags: c#, unity-container

Unity Interception can be used to intercept method, and it can capture the values of parameters of the intercepted method.

What I want is to log values of local variables within the intercepted method. For example

**Update**

```
public void CopyBlogPost(int id){

  var oldblogPost = GetBlogPost(id);

  //log details about old blog post, including name, date, id etc.

  //copy post

 //log details about new blog post, including name, date, id etc.

}
```

Is there tool that I can use for this scenario?

**Update**

As @Aron suggests, Mono.Cecil might provide the functionality.

Comment: This can only be possibly done using IL weaving. Unity Interception can use method meta data to work out the parameters etc... However internal workings is impossible, since for one thing, the compiler could inline out variables etc. Just your compiler settings could have an effect. PS IL Weaving is very very hard.

Comment: Are there other tools that have the functionality?

Comment: Why don't you update your question and give us more information about the actual problem you try to solve. I can't imagine you really want to do this with a `Add` method. By doing so, we can give you feedback on your design.

Comment: @Steven, I updated the sample for a scenario that I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is define a decorator like this:

```cs
public class LoggingCalculatorDecorator : ICalculator
{
    private readonly ICalculator decoratee;
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public LoggingCalculatorDecorator(
        ICalculator decoratee,
        ILogger logger)
    {
        this.decoratee = decoratee;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public void Add(int i, int j)
    {
        var logging = "adding "+i+" "+j;
        //Log logging variable, or any local variables

        // call decoratee
        this.decoratee.Add(i, j);
    }
}
```

This way you can add this behavior to the existing class without having it to change. If you find yourself adding many logging decorators throughout the system (and violating the DRY principle), you are probably missing a common abstraction in the system. Take a look at [this](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) and [this](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92) article. They might you some clues about how to design your system in a way that you don't have to fallback to interception and code weaving, but address the problems at the core: the design of your application.

Comment: The code provided might be a solution for this scenario. But it is not the ideal one, because the local variables vary. For example, logging for local variables within the Add() that cannot be decorated. But as you mention, if there is no such tool, I might have to consider a common abstraction layer. I will have a look at the articles. Thanks.

Comment: The OP asked for variable logging. You have here ARGUMENT logging.

Comment: @Pingpong: I'm sorry, I missed "log values of local variables within the intercepted method". Without having any more information about your typical case I would say you are doing it wrong. When you write SOLID code, the chance that you need to do such a thing is very rare. But if you do need this, your only option is using code weaving tools (as Aron said) such as PostSharp.

Comment: An added extra bit of fun comes from the fact that in most people's programs, local variables are changed during the life cycle of the method (at a very high level most of them change from null->not null). Any attempt to log your variable would require you to specify WHEN you are logging said variable.

Comment: @Steven thanks. I was considering using PostSharp, if it has the functionality.

Comment: @Pingpong: As a matter of fact, I'm not advicing PostSharp *at all*. Although I think it is useful in certain corner case scenarios (and can really shine there), in my experience most cases developers are abusing the tool to work around design flaws in their software. Unfortunately, most of the time those developers have no idea that there is something wrong with the design of their application. And note that I have no doubt that you can do this with PostSharp, it will be pretty hard to do this in a reliable way.

Comment: Mono.Cecil does ALLOW you to do it. In the same way that a needle, a magnet and a steady hand ALLOWS you to do it.

Comment: Thanks. I will have a look.